# How to set a default keyboard across an entire iOS app?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitextfield, uikit, uitextview

I have an `iPad` app that uses thousands of `UITextFields` and `UITextViews` throughout it. When text is being entered into these elements, the iOS default `keyboard` is used. However, because my app does not provide `dictation` support, it crashes whenever the user attempts to dictate. Some research into the subject has shown that it isn't possible to disable the `dictation` feature on the default `keyboard`.

Instead, I found that it is recommended to use a change the type of `keyboard` to one that doesn't offer a `dictation` option. The problem is that I have thousands of `UITextFields` and `UITextViews` throughout my app, so manually going in and changing the keyboard type of each of these is unfeasible. My question is this: is there a way to change the default `keyboard` used within an app?

Comment: do you mean auto text ? You can disable auto suggests by keyboard

Comment: Dictation is different from auto text. Auto text suggests words as you type them, dictation allows the user to speak into their phone/ipad and translates their voice into text

Comment: If you dont want the dication button to appear, you can change the keyboard type to UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;

Comment: Please read my post fully, as that is exactly what I want to do haha

Comment: why you want to change the keyboard type for each text field  when your app doesnt support dictation?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The default keyboard offers a dictation button. We do not support it and so the button causes a crash. Because of this we need our entire app to use another keyboard, one which doesn't have a dictation button. Simple as that.

Comment: can you please explain this: "so I manually going in and changing the keyboard type of each of these is unfeasible."

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about doing this is to use a category and set the value during init. This requires swizzling, but should be safe.

Keep in mind that this will do what you are requesting, so ALL UITextFields will now present using the defined keyboard type (even if you didn't instantiate the text field yourself).

This category will default all UITextFields to display the number pad.

```
#import "UITextField+KeyboardType.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UITextField (KeyboardType)

+(void)initialize {

    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], @selector(init));
    Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], @selector(init_swizzled));
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
}

- (instancetype)init_swizzled {
    self = [self init_swizzled];
    if (self) {
        self.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

I would recommend that you instead create subclasses of UITextField/UITextView and replace all existing instances of UITextField/UITextView with their new subclasses.